# Restarting pm2 from cron/shellJS - bcrypt version error

Tags: node.js, bash, bcrypt, pm2, shelljs

I'm trying to set up a `crontab` process in Ubuntu 18.04 to periodically check on the status of `pm2` and restart it if necessary.  Because I'm more familiar with JavaScript, I decided to have the crontab process run a node file that gets a JSON readout from pm2 to check the status of each app within pm2.  If any issues are detected, the JS file will executes another `bash` script using `shellJS`.  So it goes:

1. Crontab
2. Node script
3. If there is an issue with the pm2 app, execute bash script
4. Delete existing pm2 app and start a fresh instance of it

However, when I do this originating from the JS file, I get the following error originating from bcrypt:

```
Error: The module '/root/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myProject/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/myProject/models/User.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

It's very bizarre.  If I run the bash script from the command line or if I run the command directly in the command line, I don't get the error - only when I initiate it from shellJS/node.

Here's the line to call it from node:

`shell.exec('/var/scripts/restart-pm2.sh')`

Here's the line in the `restart-pm2.sh` file:

`pm2 start /root/ecosystem.config.js --only index`

And again, running that exact command works fine.

**UPDATE:**

I tried running the bash script directly from cron and I also get the error.  So it's apparently not shellJS/node that are driving the error but something about the cron context.

Comment: Do you happen to be using a node version manager such as `n`, `nvm`, or `nvs`?

Comment: I was able to find it and added an answer.  I'm not sure what other version of node it could referencing other than what's at `/usr/local/bin/node` but that seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.  I noticed when testing the bash script that I needed to make sure I had absolute path references in the `ecosystem.config.js` file to make it work from the bash script/cron.  Apparently, that file also needs an absolute reference to the node version.  For whatever reason, it only needs this when called from cron.

So in the app arguments in `ecosystem.config.js`, I added the `--interpreter` flag to reference the absolute path of the current version of node:

```
const index = {
    name: 'index',
    script: '/root/myProject/index.js',

    ...other arguments

    interpreter: "/usr/local/bin/node" // added this line
}
```